# Does the following function exist?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a function $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ other than $\sin(x)$ such that $f$ is bounded, infinitely differentiable and $f|_{[a,\infty)}(x)= \sin(x)$, $a\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: One idea is to consider power series expansion for sine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}1-e^{1/x} & x\le0\\1 & x>0\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
f(x)=g(x-a)\sin x.
$$

Comment: I think the exponent should be just $\frac{1}{x}$ rather than $-\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: The exponent is correct.

Comment: Since $\lim_{x\to 0^-} e^{-\frac{1}{x}} $ is  $\infty$, and if consider $e^{\frac{1}{x}} $, is not defined for $x=0$. Consider 
$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1-e^{\frac{1}{x}}, & \mbox{if } x<0 \\ 1, & \mbox{if } x\geq 0\end{cases}$ with $f(x)$ as by @Julian

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right.